# Python: Accept multiple arguments

Tags: python, printing

In Python I am trying to make a function that can accept 1 or more arguments. For simplicity let's say I want to make a function that prints all the arguments that are passed

```
def print_all(**arguments**):
    print(arg1, arg2, ..., argN)
```

so `print_all("A", "B")` would output `AB`.

The number of arguments passed could be 1 or more strings.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\*args and \*\*kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***args and **kwargs** allow to pass any no of arguments, positional (*) and keyword (**) to the function

```
>>> def test(*args):
...     for var in args:
...         print var
... 
>>>
```

For no of variable

```
>>> test("a",1,"b",2)         
a
1
b
2

>>> test(1,2,3)
1
2
3
```

For list & dict

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> test(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> b = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
>>> test(b)
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

**[For detail](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the usage of `*args` which allows you to pass multiple arguments to function without caring about the number of arguments you want to pass.

Sample example:

```
>>> def arg_funct(*args):
...     print args
...
>>> arg_funct('A', 'B', 'C')
('A', 'B', 'C')
>>> arg_funct('A')
('A',)
```

Here this function is returning the tuple of parameters passed to your function.

For more details, check: [**What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

Answer (score 0):

Simply this:

```
def print_all(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the splat operator (`*`) to pass one or more positional arguments.  Then join them as strings in your function to print the result.

```
def print_all(*args):
    print("".join(str(a) for a in args))

>>> print_all(1, 2, 3, 'a')
123a
```